# Run-time error '1004' passing worksheet name

Tags: vba, excel

The following function is designed to loop through a series of column headings and return the column number of a chosen header. The function gets the search name and the sheet where the search is performed.

```
Function getColumn(name As String, sheet As Worksheet) As Integer

Dim k As String, flag As Boolean, column As String

flag = False
k = 1

Do While flag <> True
    column = sheet.Cells(1, k).Value
    If column = name Then
        flag = True
    Else
        flag = False
        k = k + 1
    End If
Loop

getColumn = k

End Function
```

It has worked in previous sheets, but this line is highlighted as the error spot.

```
column = sheet.Cells(1, k).Value
```

I've tried passing the sheet name in a number of ways. As Sheet9, without quotes, as Sheet("PAYABLES"), etc.

I've also tried changing the argument type, so that sheet is a String and having this:

```
column = Sheets(sheet).Cells(1, k).Value
```

But no luck!

PLZ HALP

Comment: Try changing k to a Long instead of a string.

Comment: But you could do:`getColumn = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(name,sheet.Range("1:1"),0)` and skip everything else.

Comment: That was leftover from when I was playing around with using `sheet.Range("A" & k).Value` though that wasn't any help either

Comment: How are you calling `getColumn`?

Comment: You need to change K to a long. Have you tried putting in a breakpoint at that point to see what the value of K is?

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling the function from a worksheet cell, then you should pass the worksheet *name* rather than a worksheet *object*:

```
Function getColumn(name As String, sheetn As String) As Long
Dim k As Long, flag As Boolean, column As String

flag = False
k = 1

Do While flag <> True
    column = Sheets(sheetn).Cells(1, k).Value
    If column = name Then
        flag = True
    Else
        flag = False
        k = k + 1
    End If
Loop

getColumn = k
End Function
```

will work:

[image]

It would be better if you include error-handling logic.

Comment: If OP wanted to, for whatever reason, keep it `Function getColumn(name As String, sheet As Worksheet) As Integer`, would you have to pass `sheet` like `=getColumn("qwerty",Worksheets("Sheet1"))`?

Comment: You can't pass a sheet directly, but you could pass a range and get the sheet from that in the code.